# How to retrive data from an existing table in database using CriteriaBuilder but without using pojo classes in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

`CriteriaBuilder builder=session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query =builder.createQuery();` is this code can be used if I want to retrive data from for ex. Student table in db but I have not created pojo classs for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you need pojo class for Student table.,
the syntax builder.createQuery(Class) needs pojo class as input.